# ASP.NET: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET MVC 3 site running on IIS 6.0.

Currently when I request a page from the server it gives the following error:

> Parser Error Message: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage.

on this line:

```
<add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="NS.MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyDatabase" applicationName="/MySite"/>
```

I'm completely stumped and don't have much of a clue about the ASP.NET application lifecycle, let alone the differences between 6.0 and 7.0. Reading through the MSDN pages on it hasn't seemed to help much.

Does anyone have any insight or any good links for investigation? :)

Comment: I have the same issue with MVC 2 on the VS localhost webserver (Cassini).

Comment: This same problem (and resolution) appears to be applicable to MVC 3 on IIS 7.0 as well.

Comment: Also have this problem with MVC4 & IIS6, with a new project.  Fixed by removing webmatrix.*, see below answer.

Comment: I had the same error, but not in the context of a membership provider, so the accepted answer was no help. Turns out I'd made a stupid mistake, not specifying the assembly in the configuration section. I changed the section name to "fully.qualified.name.of.type, assembly.name" to clear the error.

Answer (score 255):

Add this in your web.config (in the appSettings section):

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```

EDIT:

For the ones who ask why, it is a known issue described in the mvc 3 [release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes)
More details [here](http://brockallen.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/beware-bin-deployment-of-mvc-and-razor-with-formsauthentication/)

Comment: Can you please expand on that a little? Where in the web.config? What do the keys do? I'm having trouble finding online documentation of those keys.

Comment: @Kennet Belenky : In the appSettings section

Comment: I see. It automatically defines security and membership rules so you have to override them before you add custom ones. Tricky.

Comment: I create a new project, this error does not occur, and I do not need to add these keys. On my existing project, I had to add these keys to work, why??

Comment: Why? Can someone please link to some explanation/documentation?

Comment: Worked a charm, but like the others - I'm after an explanation!

Comment: I've literally spent the entire day searching for an answer... Two simple statements in the Web.Config did the trick.. Thank you so much.

Comment: The first line fixed it for me in MVC4: <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>

Comment: I was getting this error from providers being added within the `<healthMonitoring>` tags and this suggestion did *not* work. Not sure what the workaround actually is as disabling healthMonitoring was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

After upgrading some of my applications from ASP.NET MVC3 to MVC4 I was getting this error.  It was a result of the WebMatrix assemblies (WebMatrix.WebData.dll and WebMatrix.Data.dll).  I removed those references and assemblies from the /bin directory and that took care of the issue.

Comment: @rboarman - This has fixed it for me repeatedly.  Are you sure the assemblies are not still sitting in the /bin directory?

Comment: Adding the key as described above fixed it. The presence of WebMatrix.WebData.dll and WebMatrix.Data.dll didn't make a difference either way.

Comment: This fixed it for me  when I upgraded from MVC4RC to RTM.  I started out by making a fresh project and copying over all the related bits.  I made no code changes, and the web.config had no significant changes either.  Strange.

Comment: Fixed it for me. I was in a situation where I installed a few things for Azure, built the project, decided that wasn't what I wanted and did an undo through TFS, so all my code was IDENTICAL to what it was when it was working. However, my bin folder was a bit heavier. Clearing the WebMatrix assemblies out manually (as opposed to calling Clean on the project) worked. Thanks Ek0nomik.

Comment: This fixed it for me also. These references are added by the MVC4 NuGet package but it looks like they are not necessary when publishing.

Comment: I'm still having this problem (stuck on an old MVC) -- where are the assemblies coming from?

Answer (score 8):

@Ek0nomik is right. We migrated from the [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) to the new [`ExtendedMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.extendedmembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) allowing us to take advantage of some of the new functionality offered in the [WebMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) namespace. By default Simple Membership is enabled for some reason so we had to disable it explicitly since we didn't want to go as far as using the [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

All we had to do was add this to the web.config:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Having Simple Membership enabled caused the Provider initialisation code to execute before the Application_Start handler. Our app structure requires App_Start to be the first thing to execute. Personally I would always expect this but Simple Membership changes this behaviour. Beware.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I just got this error, and it resulted from having accidentally copied a .cshtml into the root of my project.  It wasn't even included in the project.  Deleted that and the error went away.  This was with MVC3 on IIS7.  I imagine some of the people getting this problem are in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by any of a number of Reflection calls being made too early in an Application. It just so happens the Web.Config suggestions in other answers prevented one such Reflection call from being made. In my case however:

I'm using Entity Framework, and ran `update-database`. I got:

> This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.

As it turns out we had code that used a library which was recently modified to get all code in all namespaces/projects. Specifically, it called:

```
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

Kaboom. That caused this obscure error. EF Migrations run in a weirdo zone where the application is half running and half not, meaning the above method can never be called by any code Migrations would call on.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

Ensure the `<configSection>` elements in your `Web.config` file are fully-qualifeid type-names **including the assembly-name**.

For example, I had this:

```
<section name="mySection" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
```

...but once I changed it to this (below) that solved the problem:

```
<section name="mySection" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

### Long version:

Another cause of this issue is having a `<configSection><section name="mySection" type="MySectionHandler">` element such that the `type="MySectionHandler"` attribute is not a fully-qualified type-name including the assembly-name.

For example, this `Web.config` file will cause the first-chance exception on startup (screenshot below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <configSections>
        <section name="mySection" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>

    <mySection>
        <add key="foo" value="bar" />
    </mySection>
</configuration>
```

[image]

---

The stack-trace is:

```
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(string typeName = "System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler", bool throwOnError = true, bool ignoreCase = false)
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(string typeName = "System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler", bool throwOnError = true)
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.GetConfigType(string typeName = "System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler", bool throwOnError = true)
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost host = {System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost}, string typeString = "System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler", bool throwOnError = true)
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "machine/webroot/2", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "mySection")
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "machine/webroot/2", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "mySection")
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.RuntimeConfigurationFactory(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord = ConfigPath = "machine/webroot/2", System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "mySection")
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord factoryRecord = FactoryRecord "mySection")
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(string configKey = "mySection", out bool isRootDeclaredHere = false)
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(string configKey = "mySection", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = true, bool getRuntimeObject = true, bool requestIsHere = true, out object result = null, out object resultRuntimeObject = null)
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(string configKey = "mySection", bool getLkg = false, bool checkPermission = true)
System.Configuration.dll!System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(string configKey = "mySection")
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetApplicationSection(string sectionName = "mySection")
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(string sectionName = "mySection")
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(string sectionName = "mySection")
```

I took a look at the calling method, `System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType` and I saw that the `BuildManager.GetType(...)` call is because it's loading the `<configSection>` types, and that it only calls `EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()` if the `type=""`  attribute does not include the assembly-name - so it assumes the type-name is a reference to a class defined in `App_Code` (which doesn't have an assembly-name at this point).

[The `GetType` method spells it out quite simply](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System.Web/Compilation/BuildManager.cs#L1298):

```
class BuildManager
{
    public static Type GetType(string typeName, bool throwOnError, bool ignoreCase) {
        // If it contains an assembly name, just call Type.GetType().  Do this before even trying
        // to initialize the BuildManager, so that if InitializeBuildManager has errors, it doesn't
        // affect us when the type string can be resolved via Type.GetType().
        Type type = null;
        if (Util.TypeNameContainsAssembly(typeName)) {
            type = Type.GetType(typeName, throwOnError, ignoreCase);

            if (type != null) {
                return type;
            }
        }

        // [snip]

        _theBuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled(); // <-- Throws the exception
}
```

So the workaround is straightforward: just ensure that `Util.TypeNameContainsAssembly(typeName)` is `true`, by changing this:

```
<section name="mySection" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
```

to this:

```
<section name="mySection" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```