# Problem using microsoft-mvc-helpers package with custom membership provider in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, membership-provider, nuget

I've created an MVC 3 web application project and used the Nuget Package Manager to install the microsoft-mvc-helpers package. In order to get that to work I had to add a reference to WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData (setting "Copy Local" to true).

When I try to run my project I get the following error:

> this method cannot be called during
>   the application's pre-start
>   initialization stage.

And it points to the following section in my web.config (specifically the add tag):

```
<membership defaultProvider="ICNMemberProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ICNMemberProvider" type="Website.Providers.ICNMemberProvider" />
    </providers> 
</membership>
```

This was working before I installed the microsoft-mvc-helpers package and works if I uninstall it. Any ideas why my customer Membership Provider and the helpers package would cause this error?

Comment: I don't think there is a package named microsoft-mvc-helpers. Did you mean microsoft-web-helpers? Also, can you include the stack of the exception you're getting. Thanks!

Comment: @David, there is no stack, it says it is a configuration error and points to the section I included of the web.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this question on another stack overflow question:

[ASP.NET: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626647/asp-net-this-method-cannot-be-called-during-the-applications-pre-start-initiali)

You just have to add the following to the appSettings section of your web.config:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```