# Using System.Web.Providers with Sql Compact

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce, membership-provider

Following the [article shanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) i'm trying to use "System.Web.Providers" so you can use memberships, rules and profiles with Sql Server Compact.

I installed via Nuget, created a Users.sdf database and copied to the App_Data folder.
My Web.config was as follows:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="DefaultProfileProvider"
      type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider"
      connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
      applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="DefaultSessionProvider"
      type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider"
      connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
      applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Sql_CE" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Users.sdf;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I can not use "aspnet_regsql" because it generates the tables to a SQL Server based

The following error occurs when trying to access the "Web Site Administration Tool" on page security

> There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store.
>
> The following message may help in
>   diagnosing the problem: The
>   pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type
>   WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode
>   threw an exception with the following
>   error message: This method cannot be
>   called during the application's
>   pre-start initialization stage.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626647/asp-net-this-method-cannot-be-called-during-the-applications-pre-start-initiali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rename your connection string to DefaultConnection and remove the \ in front of Users.sdf like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Users.sdf;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

You say that you

> created a Users.sdf database

how? The Providers framework and SqlCe should do this for you. Try deleting the Users.sdf from the App_Data folder and try accessing the "Web Site Administration Tool" again. The provider engine should recreate it for you.

Comment: Corrected the error, but now there is another error.

This method can not be called During the application's pre-start initialization

Searching the net, I found this article, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626647/asp-net-this-method-cannot-be-called-during-the-applications-pre-start-initiali
 
and did what Gregoire said and it worked!
But I had a doubt why when I create a new project, this error does not occur, and I do not need to add these keys. On my existing project, I had to add these keys to work.